# Laravel eager loading sort by count of relationship entries/values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sorting, eloquent

I have products which have also comments. This comments can be voted and comments can also have child comments.

Now I want to sort these comments by date, amount of likes and amount of child comments.

Before I show you my tries I will show you my code:

Product.php (Model)

```
namespace App;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * @Protected_variables
     */

    protected $with = ['comments', 'user'];

    /**
     * @Relationships
     */

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

As you can see, I already tell Laravel with the variable `$with` to load `comments` and `user` always when loading a product.

ProductController.php

```
public function show(Product $product, Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('sorting') && in_array($request->sorting, ['Beliebtesten', 'Diskutiertesten', 'Neusten'])){
        if($request->sorting == 'Neusten'){
            $product->load(['comments' => function ($query) {
                $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
            }]);
        }else if($request->sorting == 'Diskutiertesten'){
            $product->load(['comments.children' => function ($query) {
                $query->orderBy('published_date', 'asc');
            }]);
        }else{
            $product->load('comments')->get()->sortByDesc(function($product)
            {
                return $product->likes->count();
            });
        }

        return response()->json([
            'product' => $product
        ]);
    }else{
        $product->load('comments');

        return response()->json([
            'product' => $product
        ]);
    }
}
```

So, I have two questions now:

1. Do I even need `$product->load('comments')`? - Because I have figured out when I just pass the `$product` without executing `$product->load('comments')` I also have the comments loaded... Looks like I don't need it. Is that right?
2. How can I sort the comments by amount of likes (rows, because you can only upvote) and by amount of child comments (rows)?

This is what I have tried so far (all not working for me):

1.

```
$product->load('comments')
    ->withCount('likes')
    ->orderBy('likes_count','DESC')
    ->get();
```

2. 

```
$product->loadCount('comments');

$product->orderBy('comments_count', 'desc');
```

Comment: I don't see `likes` relation in Product model, but you use it in `return $product->likes->count();` for example. Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't see it because I haven't posted the `comments` model. The `comments` model also has a `$with` attribute which has `likes` and `children`, of course!

Comment: I understand, but using syntax like `$product->likes` won't work because `likes` is not product's property. It belongs to comment model.

Answer (score 0):

1:

```php
$comments = $product->comments;
$comments->loadCount('likes');
$comments->sortByDesc('likes_count');
```

2:

```php
$product->loadCount('comments');
$product->sortByDesc('comments_count');
```